# XACML 3.0 and rfc822Name attribute

Tags: xacml3, balana

I am new to XACML. I'm using `Balana` and I think I got the basic so I am experimenting with `Target`, `Rule` and `Condition`. My policy is made by two rules. First rule applies to everyone have `med.example.com` (yes the basic example OASIS provides) in ther subject's name and if your subject's name is `jim@med.example.com` you get a PERMIT as response. I known it is redundant. Second rule says everyone won't satisfy first rule's condition will get back a DENY. What I want to do is to use a `rfc822Name` attribute both in `Target` and `Condition`. Is it possible? This is my policy definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17
  http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd"
  PolicyId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:PolicyWithDENYRule" 
  RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
Version="1.0">
<Description>
    Medi Corp access control policy
</Description>
<Target />
<Rule RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:OnlyJimShallPass"
    Effect="Permit">
    <Description>Any subject with an e-mail name in the med.example.com domain can perform any action on any resource.</Description>
    <Target>
        <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:rfc822Name-match">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">med.example.com</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id"
                        DataType="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:data-type:rfc822Name" />
                </Match>
            </AllOf>
        </AnyOf>
    </Target>
    <Condition>
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
            <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">jim@med.example.com</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id"
                        DataType="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:data-type:rfc822Name" />
        </Apply>
    </Condition>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="defaultRule" />
```

While I try to evaluate my request I got this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: second arg has to be a bag
2017-05-19 09:33:34 ERROR FileBasedPolicyFinderModule:248 - Fail to load policy : /home/pezzati/workspace/SecurityProofOfConcept/src/test/resources/policywithdenyrule/policy.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal parameter
at org.wso2.balana.cond.FunctionBase.checkInputsNoBag(FunctionBase.java:419)
at org.wso2.balana.cond.HigherOrderFunction.checkInputs(HigherOrderFunction.java:421)
at org.wso2.balana.cond.Apply.<init>(Apply.java:89)
at org.wso2.balana.cond.Apply.getInstance(Apply.java:227)
at org.wso2.balana.cond.Apply.getInstance(Apply.java:188)
at org.wso2.balana.cond.ExpressionHandler.parseExpression(ExpressionHandler.java:53)
at org.wso2.balana.cond.Condition.getInstance(Condition.java:177)
at org.wso2.balana.Rule.getInstance(Rule.java:237)
at org.wso2.balana.Policy.<init>(Policy.java:303)
at org.wso2.balana.Policy.getInstance(Policy.java:382)
at org.wso2.balana.finder.impl.FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.loadPolicy(FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.java:242)
at org.wso2.balana.finder.impl.FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.loadPolicies(FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.java:202)
at org.wso2.balana.finder.impl.FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.init(FileBasedPolicyFinderModule.java:91)
at org.wso2.balana.finder.PolicyFinder.init(PolicyFinder.java:149)
at org.wso2.balana.PDP.<init>(PDP.java:97)
at edu.pezzati.sec.xaml.XacmlTest.getPDP(XacmlTest.java:20)
at edu.pezzati.sec.xaml.PolicyWithDenyRule.init(PolicyWithDenyRule.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Why this exception? XACML 3.0 says you can use AttributeDesignator in Condition. Is there any restriction I miss? Complete project can be found [here](https://github.com/fpezzati/SecProof/tree/feature/xacml_3_0). Look at the `PolicyWithDenyRule` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it works. I was confronting two values of different type. I changed my `Condition` this way:

```
<Condition>
  <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
    <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:rfc822Name-equal"/>
    <AttributeValue DataType="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:data-type:rfc822Name">jim@med.example.com</AttributeValue>
    <AttributeDesignator MustBePresent="false"
      Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
      AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id"
      DataType="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:data-type:rfc822Name" />
  </Apply>
</Condition>
```

I changed the main function from `string-equal` to `rfc822Name-equal` and change the `AttributeValue` who holds `jim@med.example.com` from `string` to `rfc822Name`. This way main condition's function can check a `rfc822Name` attribute against a `rfc822Name` bag of attributes behaving as expected.
I also update my project on github, now it works.

Comment: Just to clarify: Balana's error message `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: second arg has to be a bag` is wrong so not helpful here. Indeed, the second arg in your original policy is an AttributeDesignator which always returns a bag, so it is correct from this point of view. Only the function (string-equal) and first arg datatype (string instead of rfc822Name) were not correct.

Comment: @CyrilDangerville hello. I see you have some experience in AuthZ. Can you point me to some docs or code examples? Thankyou.

Comment: I have some experience with XACML, but not with the Balana implementation per se, at least not recently (I tried it years ago but it gave me too much trouble so I gave up on it). I use another open source alternative: [AuthzForce](https://authzforce.ow2.org) (I am one of the maintainers). There is a section _Example of usage..._ if you want some code sample with the Java API. There is also support for REST API (with [sample code](https://gitlab.ow2.org/authzforce/server#examples-of-usage-and-pep-code-with-a-web-service-authorization-module) as well).

Comment: ... I know others use [OpenAZ](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openaz) but I have not tried it. Then there are commercial ones: Axiomatics, Oracle, etc.

Comment: @CyrilDangerville well AuthzForce looks also good. I am giving it a try just now.

Comment: The [Usage section](https://github.com/authzforce/core#usage) will get you started for most use cases. In general, the BasePdpEngine class is the entry point, esp. its getInstance(...) methods. Then most info is in the API Javadoc that we publish with the sources on Maven central (e.g. authzforce-ce-core-pdp-engine-XXX-javadoc.jar) with every release, so that your IDE can download and show them automatically, if properly configured. If something is not clear, you can ask a question on the [Github issues](https://github.com/authzforce/core/issues) or use the mailing list (see Support section).

Comment: See also https://alfa.guide for more examples and information on functions and datatypes